# exclude html attributes in str_replace

Tags: php, wordpress, replace, str-replace

so i'm trying to do the usual replacing each instance of a company name in wordpress, and i've run into an issue where on occasion (usually in the href of links) it's breaking links.

code i'm using (includes a filter for ACF custom fields)

```
    //Replace the word lunch with a span
function replace_text_wps($text){
    $replace = array(
        // 'WORD TO REPLACE' => 'REPLACE WORD WITH THIS'
        'lunch!' => '<span class="lunch">lunch!</span>',
        'Lunch!' => '<span class="lunch">lunch!</span>',
        'LUNCH!' => '<span class="lunch">lunch!</span>'
    );
    $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_text_wps');
add_filter('the_title', 'replace_text_wps');
add_filter('acf_the_content', 'replace_text_wps');
```

Is there a way to only replace it outside of stuff like href tags? i've looked into stuff like DOM parses but i'm not sure if there's a simpler method- it doesn't seem to cause grief in any other instances so i'm not sure that pre=processing the entire HMTL and looking for the word is appropriate. I did wonder about searching for the string including a space before and after it, but i wasn't sure how to include leading / trailing spaces, and it felt a bit bodge-y?
Thanks in advance!
Pete

Answer (score 1):

ok, so in this instance, which is quite specific, i've found the following code works well enough. added trailing / leading spaces in the initial matching parameters, and also variants to find it directly after html tags including with a space.
less elegant, but sufficient for the purpose here.

```
function replace_text_wps($text){
    $replace = array(
        // used mid-line
        ' lunch! ' => ' <span class="lunch">lunch!</span> ',
        ' Lunch! ' => ' <span class="lunch">lunch!</span> ',
        ' LUNCH! ' => ' <span class="lunch">lunch!</span> ',
        // used at end of lines
        ' lunch!' => ' <span class="lunch">lunch!</span>',
        ' Lunch!' => ' <span class="lunch">lunch!</span>',
        ' LUNCH!' => ' <span class="lunch">lunch!</span>',
        // used inside html tags like headers
        '>lunch!' => '><span class="lunch">lunch!</span>',
        '>Lunch!' => '><span class="lunch">lunch!</span>',
        '>LUNCH!' => '><span class="lunch">lunch!</span>',
        //used directly after html tags
        '> lunch!' => '> <span class="lunch">lunch!</span>',
        '> Lunch!' => '> <span class="lunch">lunch!</span>',
        '> LUNCH!' => '> <span class="lunch">lunch!</span>',
        //exclude alt tags on images, title attributes etc
        '"lunch!' => '"lunch!',
        'lunch!"' => 'lunch!"',
        '"Lunch!' => '"lunch!',
        'Lunch!"' => 'lunch!"'
    );
    $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_text_wps');
add_filter('the_title', 'replace_text_wps');
add_filter('acf_the_content', 'replace_text_wps');
```

Comment: After the waiting period runs out, make sure to accept your answer so that everybody knows the problem has been solved. Unless of course you want to wait if someone comes up with a better solution.